# Creating a new array object is causing several errors to come up

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Sorry if this is an easy fix, but I'm new to Java and I'm stumped. 
As the title says, when I'm trying to create a new array on line 41 I get the following error:

> Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

If I delete the semi-colon, I get three additional errors on lines 44, 48 and 51 which is in the `try`-`catch` block.

If I delete the entire line:

```
Reservation reservation[] = new Reservation[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

I get the same error message for the scanner object that is above the array on line 38.

Also, the final curly brace that is at the bottom of the class is also generating an error message saying that I need to add a curly brace, but that seems to be just an extra brace with no partner and does not remove any of the above errors.

I've attached all of my code for this class and can attach the reservation class upon request. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirlineInput
{

    final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
    final String DATA_FILE = "AirlineData.txt";
    final String TRANSACTION_FILE = "Transactions.txt";
    int count; //counter for array

    File file = new File(DATA_FILE);

    Scanner input = null;

    //creating an array to store data from file
    Reservation reservation[] = new Reservation[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

    //opening file
    try
    {
        input = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    //file data being placed in array
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String passengerName = input.nextLine();
        String reservationNumber = input.nextLine();
        String depatureFlight = input.nextLine();
        String departureFlightDate = input.nextLine();
        String departureAirport = input.nextLine();
        String arrivalAirport = input.nextLine();
        String departureTime = input.nextLine();
        String arrivaltime = input.nextLine();
        String seat = input.nextLine();
        String returnFlight = input.nextLine();
        String returnFlightdate = input.nextLine();
        String returnDepartureAirport = input.nextLine();
        String returnArrivalAirport = input.nextLine();
        String returnDepartureTime = input.nextLine();
        String returnArrivalTime = input.nextLine();
        String returnSeat = input.nextLine();

    }

}
```

Comment: You must put the code that isn't declaring variables into a method or methods or put it inside of a `main`

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs to be in a method inside of the `AirlineInput` class.
Usually, a class has a main method, which in your case would look like this:

```
public class AirlineInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Very true, but you can elaborate some more.